# how to open the url from a .pdf file through xcode programming

Tags: iphone

i'm trying to get the url from a pdf files so that if a user double taps the url on the pdf file, it opens in a new web page.... how can i do it ? any suggestions ? i'm using Xcode 3.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provide the [PDFKit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Tasks/PDFKit_Prog_Tasks.html) API which you might want to use rather than wrting your own PDF parser.

Comment: Can we use that PDFKit in iPhone or iPad APP ? i read that PdfKitGuide and it mentioned about using MAC OS 4.0 and above.... so will this frameWork work in my project ? If not what else should i do ?


thanks for answer :)

Comment: Can we use that PDFKit in iPhone or iPad APP ? i read that PdfKitGuide and it mentioned about using MAC OS 10.4.0 and above.... so will this frameWork work in my project ? If not what else should i do ? i'm using SDK 3.2....


thanks for answer :)